# Laravel Validating Values in Array in List of Values

Tags: laravel, validation

This must be a simple question, but unable to find what I am doing wrong. I have a form (shown below) with a multi-select input. It gets sent to the validator as an array. I want to make sure the values selected in the client-side are in the pre-defined list of values.

```
<form>
<select multiple name="names[]">
    <option value="Jerry">Jerry</option>
    <option value="Susan">Susan</option>
    <option value="Tim">Tim</option>
</select>
</form>

public function postNames(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      'names.*' => 'in:Jerry,Susan,Tim',
   ]);
}
```

When I open the dev tools in the browser and change the value of them and then submit the form, the validator lets it pass even though the name in the request is not in the list as defined in the validator.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

When I dump the request it looks like this.

```
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#52 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "names" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "Robert"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the form params you send on the request that should fail? from the network tab or similar

Comment: I just posted the request parameters.

Comment: that requested parameter will pass your validation as per your rule,Post parameter which should be fail but it is passing

Comment: Just updated it. I changed the option value to "Robert" and it still passes. The "names" array isn't nested so I don't see how the ".*" is not picking up all values in the array and checking it.

Comment: I think your validation rules are fine how do you handle it when it is invalid?